# Cannot Delete Amazon RDS SQL Server Database

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, rds

I've made a mistake in the naming scheme of a database on an Amazon RDS SQL Server instance but don't seem to have permissions to delete it

[image: http://i.imgur.com/LXer7EW.png]

Can anybody give me any guidance?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Found the answer if you modify user permissions resetting instance password will also reset user permissions

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer, you just saved me 4 hours :D

If you manage the RDS Instance with Terraform and use random generated passwords super user accounts, just tainting the generated password and applying the change restores your access when you accidentally deleted yourself from some databases

Answer (score 2):

```
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.rds_drop_database  '<dbname>'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-- 1. Turn Database Mirroring OFF
ALTER DATABASE [DB_NAME] SET PARTNER OFF;
GO

-- 2. Close all existing connections
ALTER DATABASE [DB_NAME] SET single_user with rollback immediate
GO

-- 3. Drop the database
DROP DATABASE [DB_NAME];
GO
```

Answer (score -1):

None of these options worked for me. In the end it turned out to be change data capture. Once i disabled this by running command

```
exec msdb.dbo.rds_cdc_disable_db '<database name>'
```

I was able to drop the database.